# How to get image blob from ImageMagick convert command in php

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

It is possible to get a binary blob by using ImageMagick `convert` via PHP's `shell_exec()`. It's very difficult to convert such a command to PHP Imagick class. Is there any alternative way to implement this feature?

I am using Imagick like this.

```
$im = new Imagick('some image');
$im->trimImage(20000);
header ("Content-Type: image/{$im->getImageFormat()}");
echo $im->getImageBlob(); // need output in from of blob
```

I want do get output result similar to this.

```
convert imageName.png -alpha set -   white -border 1 -fill none -fuzz 3% -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" -shave 1x1 removed_edges.png
```

If ImageMagick command returns a binary blob instead of writing to a file, my problems will be solved.

Comment: You can get IM to write a PNG on stdout if that’s what you mean `convert input.jpg ... PNG:-`

Comment: Why do you need the blob? If to pass to some other tool, then as Mark Setchell said, you can simply pipe the output from Imagemagick to some other tool. You should be able to create the result as a RAW RGB format rather than PNG if that is desired and pipe that by `convert input.jpg .... RGB:-`

Comment: You can use what I suggested above with `ob_start()` and `ob_get_contents()` by the way.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell I added `PNG:-` and now it was returning image instead of writing into file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appended jpg:- after command instead of image name & it's working.

`$command = "convert imageName.png -alpha set - white -border 1 -fill none -fuzz 3% -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" -shave 1x1 jpg:-";
header ("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo shell_exec($command);`